# how to traceback an error in R optimization problem

Tags: r, debugging, optimization

I wrote the following R script to solve a nested minimax optimization problem,

xi_sol=arg min_xi max_t loginvdet(xi,t)

using package `DEoptim` (differential evolution).

```
library(DEoptim)
xl <- -1; xu <- 4
ndp <- 4
p <- function(x,t){
  a <- t[1];b <- t[2];
  1/(1+exp(-b*(x-a)))
}
f <- function(x,t){
  a=t[1];b=t[2];
  sqrt(p(x,t)*(1-p(x,t)))*c(b,a-x)
}
loginvdet <- function(xi,t){         # minimize variance
  x <- xi[1:ndp];
  w <- c(xi[(ndp+1):(2*ndp-1)],1-sum(xi[(ndp+1):(2*ndp-1)]))
  infomat <- mapply(function(x) f(x,t),x)%*%diag(w)%*%t(mapply(function(x) f(x,t),x))
  loginvdet <- -log(det(infomat))
  return(loginvdet)
}
maxfinner <- function(xi){
  maxfinner_value <- DEoptim(function(t) -loginvdet(xi,t), c(0,1), c(2.5,3))
  return(-maxfinner_value$optim$bestval)
}
xi_sol <- DEoptim(maxfinner, c(rep(xl,ndp),rep(0.1,ndp-1)), c(rep(xu,ndp),rep(0.9,ndp-1)))
```

When it runs it reports error.

```
Error in DEoptim(function(t) -loginvdet(xi, t), c(0, 1), c(2.5, 3)) : 
  NaN value of objective function! 
Perhaps adjust the bounds.
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

`warnings()` returns

```
1: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
2: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
3: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
4: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
5: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
6: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
7: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
8: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
9: In log(det(infomat)) : NaNs produced
```

Because DE is a stochastic global search optimization algorithm, I assume it attempts many unreliable solutions in the process that cause the problem. I want to check the exact value of `infomat` that produces the `NaNs` and the corresponding `x` and `w` used to produce it, which may help me better set the constraints in the optimization problem. I am not good at debugging and have tried `traceback()` and `debug()`, they are messed up seems to me. I cannot get my hands on `infomat`.